# Can we display Audit Logs or User's Activity in user friendly format in SharePoint Online (2013) Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, audit-log-reports

We have a requirement, where we have to show the user's activity in graphical format. What actions user has performed on any **SharePoint Online Site** and when?

- If user **post/edit comment, like, rate** on and Discussion Forum, Blogs
- If user **add/edit/delete a list and library** - (Discussion Forum, Image
  Library, Document Library, Calendar, Blog)
- If user **add/edit/delete items in any list and library** - (Discussion Forum, Image Library,
  Document Library, Calendar, Blog)
- When **User last logged on** a share-point site

We do not want to use any third party tool *(Google Analytics , Web trends, etc.)* to track these activities.

I would like to know that can we get these details from Audit Logs or any other reports from SharePoint (OOTB). I read and found List, Library related action we can see in Audit Logs, but it's difficult to understand by end user. Do we have any OOTB Parts or Reports which I can utilize to show the activity.

Thanks,
Viren

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no OOB web part to show these activities friendly. You need to find a third party tool like Google Analytics or develop your own web part to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can format the audit reports in excel and can use Power BI to generate reports or you can create reports using excel itself, upload excel in SharePoint library and use Excel Web Access WebPart to display the report.